# Названия классов и id кириллицей

Tags: html, css

Почему в документах HTML не используют написание классов и id русскими символами? Работает же. И не надо думать как назвать, чтобы не повториться случайно, когда их уже много.

Comment: А под ie тоже работает?

Comment: А кто его знает) Не проверял

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если заглянуть в спецификацию [здесь](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata) и [здесь](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), то можно прочитать следующее:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Принято именовать латинскими символами. Да, возможно у вас работают и кириллические, но что будет когда сайт откроется в системе, не имеющей шрифтов с кириллицей?

Стандартизация такая стандартизация ;)

Answer (score 6):

[[@CrazyTimon](/users/8133/crazytimon)](/users/8133/crazytimon), как ни странно, но работает и в осле, даже седьмой версии. Но даже, если бы в спецификации не было четко обозначенных правил, то я бы все равно придерживался "неписанного" стандарта - использоват латиницу. В противном случае, будет каша: индусы будут на своем языке писать, китайцы на своем... С ужасом представляю, если бы мне пришлось править такой код )))

```
#页脚 {
    border: 1px solid #900; // 看起来不错
}

<div id="页脚">

</div>
```